# Problem with foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I do

```
ALTER TABLE bdt.auth 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `depositor no.` 
      FOREIGN KEY ( `depositor no.` ) 
         REFERENCES bdt.depositors( `depositor no.` ) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE 
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

I get

> Can't create table 'bdt.#sql-881_140' (errno: 121)

Fields are identical
There is no defined constraints:

```
SELECT
   constraint_name,
   table_name
FROM
   information_schema.table_constraints
WHERE
   constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
AND table_schema = DATABASE()
ORDER BY
   constraint_name;
```

Result

> Empty set (0.01 sec)

Comment: You probably already have a constraint `depositor no.`,just change the name.

Comment: @Mihai Wrong! I have no constraint, no one.

Comment: @Zhigalin - The error you are getting says different. Also can happen with indexes that use the same name as outlined here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/425/error-creating-foreign-key-from-mysql-workbench and here: http://thenoyes.com/littlenoise/?p=81 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623651/error-error-1005-cant-create-table-errno-121

Comment: @Zhigalin - are you *sure* that you don't have anything like that? What about in your other question on this site, this line: CONSTRAINT pk_transactions PRIMARY KEY ( `transaction no` ) ) engine=InnoDB? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71446/creation-of-a-simple-field-failed-in-mysql

Comment: @JohnP is primary key and transaction id not foreign key and depositor no. I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you're trying to use a constraint that is already identified.

```
SELECT
   constraint_name,
   table_name
FROM
   information_schema.table_constraints
WHERE
   constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
AND table_schema = DATABASE()
ORDER BY
   constraint_name;
```

Should give you the constraints you've already established. Also, you can use SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS or SHOW INNODB STATUS after you get the error to get the logs and more information.

Comment: That constraint is not identified, so you're wrong.

Comment: The result of the query you cited above is Empty set (0.01 sec)